# Keeping specific text in sepearate divs with random images on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement, each

I currently have some script that will randomise the images when the user refreshes the page.

```
var large_images = [
  "wp-content/themes/workroomv2/images/headshot1.jpg",    
  "wp-content/themes/workroomv2/images/headshot2.jpg",    
  "wp-content/themes/workroomv2/images/headshot3.jpg",    
  "wp-content/themes/workroomv2/images/large1.jpg",   
  "wp-content/themes/workroomv2/images/large2.jpg",   
  "wp-content/themes/workroomv2/images/large3.jpg" 
];

var arr = [];

$.each(large_images,
  function(i, el) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      arr.push(el);
      if (arr.length === large_images.length) {
        $(".item.large img")
          .attr("src", function(i, src) {
            return arr[i]
        })
    }
   }, 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5))
 });
```

However I want to keep certain content with the images, as this is describing team members (name, content, button). After thinking doing the same as above but with text doesn't work due to it being random. The HTML structure is below. I will need to put text in each span.

```
    <div class="item">
        <div class="inner">
            <a href="#">
                <img id="" class="people" src="" alt="test">
                <div class="text">
                    <span class="title"></span>
                    <span class="sub-title"></span>
                    <span class="content"></span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I cannot work out where how to keep the content with the images when they are randomising. Any advice on this would be great.

Comment: You already figured out how to use index for images...why would it be any different for content? Please elaborate on where you are stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array of object and set text using the index, Here is an example

```
//Create an array of object with all the required data
var large_images = [{
    src: "wp-content/themes/workroomv2/images/headshot1.jpg",
    title: "yahooo"
}, {
    src: "wp-content/themes/workroomv2/images/headshot2.jpg",
    title: "google"
}];

//When iterating also set the text using the array element
$(".item.large img").attr("src", function(i, src) {

  //Find the title span which is child of images siblings
  $(this).next('.text').find('.title').text(arr[i].title);

  return arr[i].src
})
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var large_images = [{
    src: "wp-content/themes/workroomv2/images/headshot1.jpg",
    title: "yahooo"
  }, {
    src: "wp-content/themes/workroomv2/images/headshot2.jpg",
    title: "google"
  }];

  var arr = [];

  $.each(large_images, function(i, el) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      arr.push(el);
      if (arr.length === large_images.length) {
        $(".item.large img").attr("src", function(i, src) {

          //Find the title span which is child of images siblings
          $(this).next('.text').find('.title').text(arr[i].title);
          $(this).attr('alt', arr[i].src);
          return arr[i].src
        })
      }
    }, 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5))
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item large">
  <div class="inner">
    <a href="#" class="">
      <img id="" class="people" src="" alt="test">
      <div class="text">
        <span class="title"></span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item large">
  <div class="inner">
    <a href="#" class="">
      <img id="" class="people" src="" alt="test">
      <div class="text">
        <span class="title"></span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Makes sense now! I didn't understand how it could be completed in the array really, but I've got it now